# Homotopy groups of ball complement

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a connected closed topological manifold. Let $n$ be an integer such that $\pi_i(X)=\{0\}$ for $1\leq i \leq n$.

Let $f:B^m\to X$ be a topological embedding, where $B^m$ is the $m$-dimensional ball. Is $\pi_i(X\setminus f(B^m))=\{0\}$ for $1\leq i \leq \mathrm{min}(m, n)$?

Comment: The Alexander horned ball, whose complement has nontrivial $\pi_1$, gives a counterexample. Here $\text{min}(m,n) = 2$.

Comment: You even can get an example with $m=1, n=3$.